# Displaying only the wanted div based on menu choice

Tags: html, css

Im fairly new to programming in HTML, and I want to create a webpage that displays what i have within a  tag based on menu choice.

in meta i have something like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#chap4">Chapter 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chap5">Chapter 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Further down the code, I have something like:

```
<div class="chap4">
    content
</div>

<div class="chap5">
    content
</div>
```

Is there any way i can get the page to display only the content of  when I press the menu link to chapter 4, and only the content of chapter 5 when I press the menu link for chapter 5?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **:target** changing classes with ids.

```css
#content > div:not(:target) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#chap4">Chapter 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#chap5">Chapter 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
  <div id="chap4">
    content 4
  </div>

  <div id="chap5">
    content 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for the troubleshooting. :) Ill do some investigating on my own here. Obviously thats where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

You should use give id of that particular div.
When you want to navigate in the single web page using anchor tag
you should use id
and you can give id to any tag like span, div, table

Your New code will be like this.

```
<div id="chap4">
    content
</div>

<div id="chap5">
    content
</div>
```

Comment: using id instead of class is really not the solution

Comment: then what is you opinion about this ?

Comment: This is only a partial answer. Changing from class to id does nothing to hide/show content.